# during the installation of firebase_admin I found a problem concerning the rust

Tags: ubuntu, rust

```
 This package requires Rust >=1.56.0.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried to install it but to no avail.

Comment: What does "I tried to install it but to no avail" mean? Did you install it and it still didn't work, or could you not install it?

Comment: i install it but it doesn't work.(error reading rust version)

Comment: What exactly did you do? What commands did you type to get the traces you've shown and what commands did you type to install Rust? Also what's the output of `rustc -V`?

Comment: Reopened OP translated the question.

Comment: I've used the command "rustup toolchain install 1.56.0"

Comment: i need rust to install the library firebase-admin and to install it i've used pip install firebase-admin but i've got this error.ERROR:could not find a version that satisfies the requirement firebase-admin (from versions:none)  and ERROR: no matching distribution found for firebase-admin what should i do to solve it?

Comment: How did you install `rustup`? Did you add `$HOME/.cargo/bin` to your `PATH`? And what's the output of `rustc -V`?

Comment: yes, i add it but the problem persist.

Comment: and for the rustc -v ==> bash: rustc: commande introuvable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install rust for your computer using the instructions at https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install It cannot be installed with `pip`

On some ubuntu systems apt-get can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install rustc cargo
```

On other systems a curl pipe should be used

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

Comment: Why the downvote, this is how to install rust is there a mistake in the post?